# How can I specify the column of a dataframe I would like to add to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to be able to succinctly specify the columns I add to a list comprehension.

The basic structure of the list comprehension is very simple as follows, where spark_sql_df is a spark dataframe and column is an actual name of a column within a dataframe.

```
def return_list():
    
    # creation and munging of spark_sql_df

    my_list = [int(row.column) for row in spark_sql_df.collect()]
    
    return my_list
```

However, as I need to search through multiple dataframes, and then compare the results, to reveal missing data, I would like a way to be able to cycle through columns so that I don't have to replicate this code multiple times.

Simple I thought, I'll use the `col` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` and wrap it around my new variable and carry on as normal:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def return_list(column):
    
    # creation and munging of spark_sql_df

    my_list = [int(row.col(column)) for row in spark_sql_df.collect()]
    
    return my_list
```

When this is attempted the program raises the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<my_username>\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1527, in __getattr__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'col' is not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "microservice_junifer_compare_keys.py", line 107, in <module>
    my_list = general_junifer_key_lister(index)
  File "microservice_junifer_compare_keys.py", line 78, in general_junifer_key_lister
    for row in spark_sql_df.collect()]
  File "microservice_junifer_compare_keys.py", line 78, in <listcomp>
    for row in spark_sql_df.collect()]
  File "C:\Users\<my_username>\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1532, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: col
```

Can this be resolved in a manner that does not lead to ungainly if/else statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I request you to consider any of the other approaches to process your data other than collect. Because this brings all the data to driver and you cannot use any of the cool features of spark. So what you need can be definitely done with spark inbuilt functions or in worst case spark udf or pandas udf.

Just to help you in this approach,try this:

```
tst2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([('netflix','yahoo',1),('amazon','yahoo',2),('flipkart',None,2)],schema=("asset_domain","asset",'xtra'))
def return_list(column):
    my_list=[int(row[column]) for row in tst2.collect()]
    return(my_list)
res =return_list('xtra')
```

Because once you collect, it is an array of row elements. you need not need the col function which is meant for directly working with spark dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use square brackets, and yes I completely agree, however in my use case is fairly simple (in terms of Spark) and this is effectively the last step needed before comparatively mundane functions are used. Really enjoying spark as a language so far though so I'm sure I'll be designing plenty more scripts using it!

Comment: happy to hear :-)